# Problemas para definir source de una carpeta de funciones en R

Tags: r, script, rstudio

tengo la siguiente problemática:

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en dónde estoy utilizando scripts contenidas en una carpeta llamada "functions", en ella están contenidas varios scripts en la cual cada uno representa una función en específico, todas ellas en formato .R, a la hora de querer usarlos, previamente definiendo el Working Directory, me sale el siguiente error:

[image: Error de salida del código]

Para mayor claridad, dejaré las confiuraciones iniciales de mi código:

```
# Condiciones Generales
{
  # Librerías necesarias para el modelo.
  suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    library(tidyverse)
    library(nowcasting)
    library(readxl)
    library(openxlsx)
    library(dynlm)
    library(dfms)
    library(skimr)
    library(janitor)
    library(lmtest)
    library(vars)
    library(xts)
    library(zoo)
    library(lubridate)
  })
  # Limpiamos el entorno de trabajo (variables y objetos)
  rm(list = ls())
  # Opciones adicionales del modelo.
  options(max.print = 100000)
  # usando la afunción print() se podra visualizar mas datos.
  # Limpiamos la consola
  cat("\014")
}
###############################################################################
###############################################################################
# Setting the path of data (i.e. the "2016-06-29.xls" is the data using in 
# the DFM example in the scripts of the New York FED.)
setwd("~/BBCh/Scripts_BBCh_MVC/BBCh_Scripts/scripts_releases")
# Setting function dfm for Dynamics Factors Model.
source("functions")
```

Les agradecería que me puedan ayudar con la configuración de source para poder usar las funciones.

Gracias!

Comment: Pero `functions` ¿es un archivo o una carpeta? por que debería ser un archivo tipicamente se hace algo así `source("functions.R")`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho no, "functions" es una carpeta que contiene scripts, por eso definí que source fuera: source("functions")

Comment: Pero es que `source()` espera un archivo no una  carpeta, ahí está el problema

Answer (score 1):

El tema es que `source()` sirve para importar un único archivo `.R`, si quieres cargar todos los de una carpeta, debería obtener la lista de archivos de la carpeta y aplicar `source()` a cada uno:

```
file.sources = list.files(c("./functions"), 
                          pattern="*.R$", 
                          full.names=TRUE, 
                          ignore.case=TRUE)

sapply(file.sources, source, .GlobalEnv)
```

fuente: [Reading all scripts and data files from multiple folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291520/reading-all-scripts-and-data-files-from-multiple-folders)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Patricio Moracho por tu ayuda! lo arreglaré